# How to install multicol package?

Tags: multicol, tlmgr

I tried to use tlmgr to install multicol package via `tlmgr install multicol`, but I received the following error message: `install: package multicol not present in repository.`

How should I install this package?

Comment: multicol is part of the required core latex distribution, if you have got latex but have not got multicol, complain to the person who gave you latex. (it is part of the `tools` package of tlmgr but it is a requirement that that is distributed as part of latex)

Comment: I've downloaded it from the official distribution page..

Comment: then you will have multicol installed (or tlmgr install tools if somehow you have managed not to get that)

Comment: I have this stupid problem too, and now it says `tlmgr install: package already present: tools`. This is despite the file existing at `/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty`

Comment: Oh wait. Make sure you type `\usepackage{multicol}` and not the plural multicols.

Answer (score 0):

For installing `multicol` package use this command:

```bash
tlmgr install tools
```

Comment: Welcome. Contributions are great, but the comments make clear this is not a solution to the OP's problem.